# How to share a folder in Windows without computer name in path

Tags: windows, sharing

I have shared a folder, it is available by path \\mypcname\tmp

I want to make it available by path \\tmp

How can this be done?

Comment: I think it is impossible without a specialized driver. The protocol needs to know the host where to search the object (https://winprotocoldoc.blob.core.windows.net/productionwindowsarchives/MS-DTYP/%5bMS-DTYP%5d.pdf section 2.2.57). The closest you can get without system modification is to mount it with a drive letter on the other computer (Z: for example).

Comment: If you just don't want to remember the hostname, you could add `tmp` as alias for `mypcname` and then connect to `\\tmp\tmp` (in hosts `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows, `/etc/hosts` on linux, you might have to use the IP directly).

Comment: Can you map a drive to make it easier?